# VS2015: TF31002 Error - Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tfs, azure-devops

I'm trying to help a colleague to connect to a server URL through TFS but keep receiving this error:

*TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server:
Possible reasons for failure include:
-The name, port number, or protocol for the Team Foundation Server is incorrect.
-The Team Foundation Server is offline.
-The password has expired or is incorrect.
Technical information (for administrator):
Unable to connect to the remote server*

Now I know there is no problem with the server, as I have successfully helped 10+ other users to connect, with no problems occurring with these users. I've scoured the internet to find a solution but have come up empty so far. We've done a full uninstall and reinstall, and have also deactivated and reactivated the license to no avail. I've also disabled the firewall and AV which had no effect. I've tried his credentials on my machine and we can connect without any issues, which suggests to me it's an issue with the config on his machine. Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Can you successfully navigate to the web portal from the affected machine? Is this VS Team Services, or on-premise TFS?

Comment: What's the URL like? Do you need to add Host mapping to Host file?

Comment: @DanielMann i've just tried and it looks like we can't get onto the web portal from the affected machine. It takes too long to respond and doesn't give us a chance to enter credentials

Comment: Can you ping to tfs server successfully?

Comment: yes he can - he gets similar results on his machine as I do on mine.

Comment: @RayF Can you access your TFS with IP address (e.g. http://[ip]:8080/tfs)